# ES6 import from root

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I'm currently playing around with React Native. I'm trying to structure my app, however it's starting to get messy with imports.

```
--app/
    -- /components
        -- Loading.js
    -- index.ios.js
```

Now, within my `index.ios.js` i'm able to simply do:

`import Loading from './components/Loading';`

However, when I start to create more components, with a deeper directory struture, it starts to get messy:

`import Loading from '.../../../../components/Loading';`

I understand the preferred solution would be to make private npm modules for things, but that's overkill for a small project.

You could do a `global.requireRoot` type solution on the browser, but how do I implement this with import?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have to anything specifically to do with React or ES6.

Comment: Alias, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: I did not... The only answer I seem to found was "structure your application better" but it isn't always an option. I just ended up using require....

Comment: How is using require any different from using import here?

Comment: Might be able to try `NODE_PATH='./app' npm start` and then require things like `import Loading from 'components/Loading'` but haven't tried it myself...

Comment: Use an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Had the same issue with React.
So i wrote some plugin for babel which make it possible to import the modules from the root perspective - the paths are not shorter - but it's clear what you import.

So instead of:

```
import 'foo' from '../../../components/foo.js';
```

You can use:

```
import 'foo' from '~/components/foo.js';
```

[Here is the Plugin (tested and with a clear README)](https://github.com/michaelzoidl/babel-root-import)

Comment: Thanks for this! Incredibly useful :)

Comment: This one is very useful

Comment: How to make eslint not complain about not finding the import? (note: trying to use it in a Nodejs app, not React)

Answer (score 42):

The react documentation explain how to do that:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports

just add a jsconfig.json in your project root:

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src"
   },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution. `tsconfig.json` if TypeScript.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me! But I had to remember to restart my webpack for it to take effect.

Comment: Great. Simple and effective. `import {H1} from 'components/tags'`

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Webpack you can configure it via the **resolve** property to resolve a your import path.

*Webpack 1*

```
resolve: {
  root: [
    path.resolve(__dirname  + '/src')
  ]
}......
```

*Webpack 2*

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve(__dirname + '/src'),
    path.resolve(__dirname + '/node_modules')
  ]
}.....
```

After that you can use

```
import configureStore from "store/configureStore";
```

instead of the:

```
import configureStore from "../../store/configureStore";
```

Webpack will configure your import path from the passed resolve param.

The same stuff you can do with System.js loader but with it's own config param (it's can be  *map*  or *path*. Check it in the System.js documentation) (if you would like to use it. It's mostly for a Angular 2 case. But I suggest: don't use standard System.js even if you are working with ng2.  Webpack is much better).

Comment: This answer would be better if the example `import` statements used the paths/files in op's question.

Comment: This does not seem to work for css or image files. I have my assets in `src/assets` and I get a **Module not found** error from react that says I'm attempting to import something that falls outside the src directory. YMMV.

Answer (score 11):

I just checked out a React project which is more than 6 months old and for some reasons my imports no longer worked. I tried the first answer:

```
import 'foo' from '~/components/foo.js';
```

Unfortunately this did not work.

I added an `.env` file in the root of my project at the same level as my `package.json`. I added the following line to that file and this fixed my imports in my project.

```
NODE_PATH=src/
```

Comment: It's `import 'foo' from 'components/foo.js';`. add this too.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using [Create-React-App](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/), you just need to change the environmental variable [NODE_PATH](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) to contain the root of your project.

In your config.json do the following change to set this variable before running the react-scripts commands:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=. react-scripts start",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_PATH=. react-scripts build",
  "test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=. react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

We're using the npm library [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) because it works on unix and windows. The syntax is `cross-env var=value command`.

Now instead of `import module from '../../my/module'` we can do `import module from 'src/my/module'`

**Extra details on implementation**

Its important to note that cross-env's scope is limited to the command it executes, so `cross-env var=val command1 && command2` will only have var set during command1. Fix this if needed by doing `cross-env var=val command1 && cross-env var=val command2`

create-react-app gives precedence to folders in node_modules/ over whats in NODE_PATH, which is why we're setting NODE_PATH to "." instead of "./src". Using "." requires all absolute imports to start with "src/" which means there should never be a name conflict, unless you're using some node_module called src.

(Note of caution: The solution described above *replaces* the variable NODE_PATH. Ideally we would append to it if it already exists. NODE_PATH is a ":" or ";" separated list of paths, depending on if its unix or windows. If anyone finds a cross-platform solution to do this, I can edit my answer.)

Answer (score 7):

With webpack you can also make paths starting with for example `~` resolve to the root, so you can use `import Loading from '~/components/Loading';`:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js'],
  modules: [
    'node_modules', 
    path.resolve(__dirname + '/app')
  ],
  alias: {
    ['~']: path.resolve(__dirname + '/app')
  }
}
```

The trick is using the javascript bracket syntax to assign the property.

Comment: I doubt that the brackets do anything here. The brackets are for allowing a variable to be passed as a key. Just having quotes around the key should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

In **Webpack 3** the config is slightly diffrent:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import {resolve} from 'path';
```

...

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: ["babel-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$|\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
    alias: {
        ["~"]: resolve(__dirname, "src")
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Create React App you can add `paths.appSrc` to `resolve.modules` in `config/webpack.config.dev.js` and `config/webpack.config.prod.js`.

From:

```
resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(...
```

To:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [paths.appSrc, 'node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(...
```

Your code would then work:

```
import Loading from 'components/Loading';
```