# How can I find the root Angular directory?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Edit: Although this question was originally asked about services and I now know that services should be included in modules, the core issue was still valid when applied to importing modules too.  There is an updated answer below with the "official" way to do this now that the docs have (somewhat) evolved.

I have a service that I'd like to reference in my module/component.  All of my services are in the /_services directory, and I don't want to have to traverse backwards down the file system when I know that my service is always going to be just off the root.  If I move my component into a new subdirectory I'd like it to be resilient to this simple change and not require rework.

In other words, can I change this:

```
import { ApiService } from './../../_services/api.service';
```

into something like this?

```
import { ApiService } from '$APP_ROOT/_services/api.service';
```

Comment: Check this out: i don't know if you are using webpack but [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41181321/2160958) you go

Comment: Also [this plugin](https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import) may be helpfull for ya

Comment: Awesome!  Why don't you post these as answers?  :)

I use the approot plugin for node a lot, this seems like a great way to do it for Angular.

Comment: I don't know if you are using AngularJs or Angular2 but if it is Angular2 you should split your application into modules, then don't keep services in shared module `Do not specify app-wide singleton providers in a shared module. A lazy-loaded module that imports that shared module makes its own copy of the service.` I recommend to read this [ARTICLE](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

Comment: The question was tagged with Angular2 :)  Thanks for the link, I'll read that in detail tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a few months later and there's now an answer directly from the angular guide.  You can reference modules from the root by using the absolute path starting with "app".  For example, if you want to load the shared module you simply use this import:

```
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
```

Here it is as used in the Guide:

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#app-routing

There is also a section about this in the TypeScript guide:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: This has been updated to `import { componentName } from 'src/app/component'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use some libs that are allowing you to do this.

If you are using [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41181321/2160958) it will resolve your problem

> *Webpack 1*
>
> ```
> resolve: {
>   root: [
>     path.resolve(__dirname  + '/src')
>   ]
> }......
> ```
>
> *Webpack 2*
>
> ```
> resolve: {
>   modules: [
>     path.resolve(__dirname + '/src'),
>     path.resolve(__dirname + '/node_modules')
>   ]
> }.....
> ```
>
> After that you can use
>
> ```
> import configureStore from "store/configureStore";
> ```
>
> instead of the:
>
> ```
> import configureStore from "../../store/configureStore";
> ```

If you are not using Webpack you can simply install [Babel Root Import](https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import)

> ```
> // Usually
> import SomeExample from '../../../some/example.js';
> const OtherExample = require('../../../other/example.js');
>
> // With Babel-Root-Importer
> import SomeExample from '~/some/example.js';
> const OtherExample = require('~/other/example.js');
> ```