# How to use global to share app-root-path across modules in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using import-export in node js every time when I import a modules I will be using lots of like these ../../ then later I found a lib 'npm app-root-path' but I wanna use this lib globally by assigning it to a global variable in app.js and wanna use that across all pages.How to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~/` instead of `../../`.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31937237/2025156