# How to import starting from the root app?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to ask how to import starting from the root app directory instead of my own way of importing.? Like **socialite/resources/js/plugins/validation.js** (see full directory below).

My way of importing is like below. These code were working fine.

**Create.vue**

```
<script>
    import "../../plugins/validation.js";
</script>
```

---

[image]

Comment: There is a similar question, perhaps the answers can help -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755065/es6-import-from-root

Comment: @WillBlack already been there Sir, the solution does not help, instead it starts from the very root instead of the root app only.

Comment: @WillBlack can you show me Sir how to configure **Michael J. Zoidl**'s answer of the link you comment. And I'm curious if that will work in laravel-vuejs app, cause the github doc talks about react only.