# How to import react files from base folder?

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I want to import some functions from another folder. I just need to import it from the base folder.

```
 src
  app
   otherFolders
```

I need to import it like this 'app/otherFolder/component' not like '../../otherFolder/component'.

How can do this?

Comment: why such a specific use case? i mean the ```../../otherFolder/component``` would work just fine right?

Comment: Yeah ../../otherFolder/component, It's working fine. But as my thoughts it's not easy for read a code. That's why I'm searching for that kind of solution. 

@SampurnG

Comment: You can try looking at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755065/es6-import-from-root)

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports

This worked for me. Thank you @SampurnG